# name xrange is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

i ran the code below on jupyter notebook and it brought this error message: name 'xrange' range is not defined. i don't know what i'm doing wrong and i have [python-3.9] installed. Anyone to help please?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import random

n = 100

heads = (sc.parallelize(xrange(n))
    .map(lambda _: random.random())
    .filter(lambda r: r < 0.5)
    .count())

tails = n - heads
ratio = 1. *heads / n

print('heads =',heads)
print('tails =',tails)
print('ratio =',ratio)
```

Comment: Sounds like you installed a Python 2 package in your Python 3 environment. Get rid of it, and install a Python 3 version?

Answer (score -1):

`xrange` is a Python 2 function. The function's name has changed to `range` in Python 3.

Read the documentation of the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function for more info.

On Python 2, `range` returned full list:

```
range(5)
```

> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

And `xrange` returned an iterable object.

On Python 3, `range` returns an iterable object:

```
x = range(5)
print(x)  # range(0, 5)
print(next(x))  # 0
print(next(x))  # 1
```